# Reader and writer in multithread in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization

Here is my questions. I have two threads writer1 and writer2 who modify the attributs of a struture, the writer1 writes in attribut1, the writer2 writes in attribut2. And I have a thread Reader who reads the structure. What I'm waiting for is:  When writer1 is writing, writer2 can also write at the same time.(It dosen't cause problem because they modify the different attributs). Of course, when writer2 is writing, writer1 can also write at the same time. But when the Reader is reading the values of the structure, neither writer1 nor writer2 can be writing at the same time.I shoule be sure that the value I'm reading is not changing by other threads

Exemple:

```
typedef struct
{
    int a;
    double b;

} data;

data glob;

int main()
{

    thread reader([]()
    {
        while(1)
        {
            sleep(1s);
            cout << glob;
        }
    });

    thread writer1([]()
    { 
        while(1)
            glob.a++;
    });
    thread writer2([]()
    { 
        while(1)
            glob.b++;
    });

    int i;
    cin >>i;
}
```

Comment: While you are using pretty advanced C++ features like lambdas and threads, you seem to have problems with some more basic C++ things, like using `typedef` for structures, which is not needed as a structure name is a type-name. Doing e.g. `struct data { ... };` would make `data` a type.

Comment: As for your problem, look into [the C++ atomic library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic).

Comment: This might be a subtle problem to fully solve; the two attributes may share a cache line. The C++ semantics for `std::mutex`  and `std::atomic` can be  used to make the code correct, but this might not be fast. As for `Reader` locking out both writers concurrently, that presumably is a design mistake. As the writes are unrelated and thus unsequenced, the reads can be independent. This means the Reader can use two locks consecutively, not concurrently.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

just use mutex ;)
It's very simple to use and will solve u problem.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex

Answer (score 0):

One end of the solution plane - single mutex and a single conditional variable shared by both writers and the reader.

The opposite end - two atomic variables and reader spinning between the two.

And architecturally most clean (and also fast when done right) - Inbox queue for the reader key-ed by the writer ID so no two messages from the same writer can be queued.